# Tomcat / Maven plugin - Unauthorized error

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, deployment, unauthorized

I have the following config in my /users//settings.xml.

Under PluginsGroup:

```
  <pluginGroup>org.apache.tomcat.maven</pluginGroup>
```

Under servers:

```
  <server>
     <id>localhost</id>
     <username>tom</username>
     <password>cat</password>
   </server>
```

Under profiles:

```
 <plugin>
   <configuration>
     <server>localhost</server>
     <url>http://localhost:8080/manager/text</url>
     <path>/</path>
   </configuration>
 </plugin>
```

I ran the maven command with -X options, and I see the following:

```
[DEBUG] Reading global settings from C:\Tools\apache-maven-3.1.1\bin\..\conf\settings.xml
[DEBUG] Reading user settings from C:\Users\<user>\.m2\settings.xml
```

I have the `manager-script` role in tomcat users xml file.

When I manually verify the access through browser, it works fine. But when I run `mvn tomcat7:deploy` I get the following:

```
 Receiving response: HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
```

User name and password are correct. I verified it manually. What else could be wrong?
Googling did not help much.

Edit: More details from Log.

```
 HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
 Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
 Cache-Control: private
 Expires: Wed, 31 Dec 1969 18:00:00 CST
 WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Tomcat Manager Application"
 Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=7320C7326C51E8F7FF9F4D23A39E6971; Path=/manager/; HttpOnly
 Content-Type: text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1
 Transfer-Encoding: chunked
 Date: Thu, 24 Apr 2014 02:56:27 GMT
 Cookie accepted: "[version: 0][name: JSESSIONID][value: 7320C7326C51E8F7FF9F4D23A39E6971]     
                           [domain: localhost][path: /manager/][expiry: null]". 
 Connection can be kept alive indefinitely
 Authentication required
 localhost:8080 requested authentication
 Authorization challenge processed
 Authentication failed
 Clearing cached auth scheme for http://localhost:8080
```

**Edit:**
   Well, this is what I found out. When I pass username and password from mvn command, its working fine. But its not picking up from settings.xml.

Does it ring any bell? I tried moving the config stuff to MAVEN_HOME/config/settings.xml as well. (Deleted the user settings.xml). But still the same.

Any settings cache?

Edit:

I turned on the debugger with -X. Even though I deleted /user/.m2/settings.xml, it says its reading that file.

```
[DEBUG] Reading global settings from C:\Tools\apache-maven-3.1.1\bin\..\conf\settings.xml
[DEBUG] Reading user settings from C:\Users\<user>\.m2\settings.xml
```

How to flush?

Comment: You're sure that the username/password should not be tomcat/tomcat? That is the typical setup: `<user name="tomcat" password="tomcat" roles="admin-gui,manager-gui" />`. Triple check your tomcat-users.xml. Have you restarted Tomcat since adding the user?

Comment: It does not say login/password are incorrect. It says you do not have access to resource you are requesting

Comment: @jedison yes, I did check it a couple times. I changed the u/p. So yes, the one I posted above is correct.

Comment: @hoaz anything else to look into?

Comment: what url do you access?

Comment: http://localhost:8080/manager/text is what I pointed in maven settings.xml

Comment: Can you access that from the browser? Can you login with these credentials to that url? I think that in order to access the tomcat manager you need to go to http://localhost:8080/manager without the /text

Comment: Thats right, and it works fine with browser. I already tested it.

Answer (score 0):

The pluging configuration should be like that:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <server>text</server>
        <url>http://localhost:8080/manager/text</url>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

This should work 
I am guessing that the application you want to deploy is named **text**. If it is not replace text with your web application name. 
Also I would try removing the last `<path>/</path>` element to see if this helps or not...

Comment: /text is a tomcat URL, like /manager. And the above plugin config is not needed. Because its specified under the <plugingroup> config.

Comment: Yes I saw that you need to add that for tomcat 7. I guess I need to update my projects as well :P

Comment: Another idea is to check if you have <Servers> path in both maven settings.xml. They my might not work togeather

Comment: I checked it. and its not duplicated